My blender addon will work in the text editor but I keep getting an error when I try to install it with the .py file
I get this error
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\blender-4.2.3-windows-x64\\4.2\\scripts\\addons_core\\bl_pkg\\bl_extension_ops.py", line 1388, in execute
cmd_batch = self.exec_command_iter(is_modal)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\blender-4.2.3-windows-x64\\4.2\\scripts\\addons_core\\bl_pkg\\bl_extension_ops.py", line 2452, in exec_command_iter
self.exec_legacy(source_filepath)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\blender-4.2.3-windows-x64\\4.2\\scripts\\addons_core\\bl_pkg\\bl_extension_ops.py", line 2583, in exec_legacy
bpy.types.PREFERENCES_OT_addon_install.execute(self, bpy.context)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\blender-4.2.3-windows-x64\\4.2\\scripts\\startup\\bl_operators\\userpref.py", line 821, in execute
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=mod.__name__)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\blender-4.2.3-windows-x64\\4.2\\scripts\\modules\\bpy\\ops.py", line 109, in __call__
ret = \_op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Error: '\_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'materials'

and here is my code
bl_info = {
    "name": "Simple shader editor",
    "description": "adds a shader with a simple button press",
    "author": "John Doe, Jane Doe",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (4, 2, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}
import bpy
import mathutils


class SimpleShaderEditor (bpy.types. Panel):
    """Easy Way To Add Shaders"""
    bl_label = "Simple Shader Editor"
    bl_idname = "Shader_Editor"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row. label (text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("sse_object.remove_shader")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("sse_object.toon_shader")  
         
class toon_shader(bpy.types.Operator):

    """Adds a Toon Shader to the selected object"""
    bl_idname = "sse_object.toon_shader"
    bl_label = "Adds a Toon Shader to the selected object"
    global mat
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Toon Shader")
    mat.use_nodes = True
    @classmethod
    def poll (cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.object
        Toon_Shader_ini()
        toon_material = bpy.data.materials.get("Toon Shader")
        if obj.data.materials:
            # If the object already has materials, replace the first one with the Toon Shader
            obj.data.materials[0] = toon_material
        else:
            # If the object has no materials, append the Toon Shader
            obj.data.materials.append(toon_material)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Shader Added!")
        return {'FINISHED'}


    
    
    
class Remove_Shader(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Removes any material from the selected object"""
    bl_idname = "sse_object.remove_shader"
    bl_label = "Remove Material"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll (cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Shader Removed!")
        obj = context.object
        obj.data.materials.clear()
        return {'FINISHED'}



    
   



# Toon Shader code
def Toon_Shader_ini():
    toon_shader = mat.node_tree
    #start with a clean node tree
    for node in toon_shader.nodes:
        toon_shader.nodes.remove(node)
    toon_shader.color_tag = 'NONE'
    toon_shader.description = "Simple Toon Shader"

    #toon_shader interface
    
    #initialize toon_shader nodes
    #node Material Output
    material_output = toon_shader.nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")
    material_output.name = "Material Output"
    material_output.is_active_output = True
    material_output.target = 'ALL'
    #Displacement
    material_output.inputs[2].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    #Thickness
    material_output.inputs[3].default_value = 0.0
    
    #node Principled BSDF
    principled_bsdf = toon_shader.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
    principled_bsdf.name = "Principled BSDF"
    principled_bsdf.distribution = 'MULTI_GGX'
    principled_bsdf.subsurface_method = 'RANDOM_WALK'
    #Base Color
    principled_bsdf.inputs[0].default_value = (0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 1.0)
    #Metallic
    principled_bsdf.inputs[1].default_value = 0.0
    #Roughness
    principled_bsdf.inputs[2].default_value = 0.5
    #IOR
    principled_bsdf.inputs[3].default_value = 1.5
    #Alpha
    principled_bsdf.inputs[4].default_value = 1.0
    #Normal
    principled_bsdf.inputs[5].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    #Subsurface Weight
    principled_bsdf.inputs[7].default_value = 0.0
    #Subsurface Radius
    principled_bsdf.inputs[8].default_value = (1.0, 0.20000000298023224, 0.10000000149011612)
    #Subsurface Scale
    principled_bsdf.inputs[9].default_value = 0.05000000074505806
    #Subsurface Anisotropy
    principled_bsdf.inputs[11].default_value = 0.0
    #Specular IOR Level
    principled_bsdf.inputs[12].default_value = 0.5
    #Specular Tint
    principled_bsdf.inputs[13].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    #Anisotropic
    principled_bsdf.inputs[14].default_value = 0.0
    #Anisotropic Rotation
    principled_bsdf.inputs[15].default_value = 0.0
    #Tangent
    principled_bsdf.inputs[16].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    #Transmission Weight
    principled_bsdf.inputs[17].default_value = 0.0
    #Coat Weight
    principled_bsdf.inputs[18].default_value = 0.0
    #Coat Roughness
    principled_bsdf.inputs[19].default_value = 0.029999999329447746
    #Coat IOR
    principled_bsdf.inputs[20].default_value = 1.5
    #Coat Tint
    principled_bsdf.inputs[21].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    #Coat Normal
    principled_bsdf.inputs[22].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    #Sheen Weight
    principled_bsdf.inputs[23].default_value = 0.0
    #Sheen Roughness
    principled_bsdf.inputs[24].default_value = 0.5
    #Sheen Tint
    principled_bsdf.inputs[25].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    #Emission Color
    principled_bsdf.inputs[26].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    #Emission Strength
    principled_bsdf.inputs[27].default_value = 0.0
    #Thin Film Thickness
    principled_bsdf.inputs[28].default_value = 0.0
    #Thin Film IOR
    principled_bsdf.inputs[29].default_value = 1.3300000429153442
    
    #node Shader to RGB
    shader_to_rgb = toon_shader.nodes.new("ShaderNodeShaderToRGB")
    shader_to_rgb.name = "Shader to RGB"
    
    #node Color Ramp
    color_ramp = toon_shader.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
    color_ramp.name = "Color Ramp"
    color_ramp.color_ramp.color_mode = 'RGB'
    color_ramp.color_ramp.hue_interpolation = 'NEAR'
    color_ramp.color_ramp.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
    
    #initialize color ramp elements
    color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.remove(color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0])
    color_ramp_cre_0 = color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0]
    color_ramp_cre_0.position = 0.0
    color_ramp_cre_0.alpha = 1.0
    color_ramp_cre_0.color = (0.025554336607456207, 0.004008842166513205, 0.0077217575162649155, 1.0)

    color_ramp_cre_1 = color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.19431838393211365)
    color_ramp_cre_1.alpha = 1.0
    color_ramp_cre_1.color = (0.099205881357193, 0.010578623972833157, 0.023921657353639603, 1.0)

    color_ramp_cre_2 = color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.3886367678642273)
    color_ramp_cre_2.alpha = 1.0
    color_ramp_cre_2.color = (0.3910602331161499, 0.03194624185562134, 0.08225385844707489, 1.0)

    color_ramp_cre_3 = color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.650000810623169)
    color_ramp_cre_3.alpha = 1.0
    color_ramp_cre_3.color = (1.0, 0.07133930176496506, 0.1980886161327362, 1.0)

    
    #node Node
    node_1 = toon_shader.nodes.new("NodeFrame")
    node_1.name = "Node"
    node_1.label_size = 11
    node_1.shrink = False
    
    #Set parents
    color_ramp.parent = node_1
    
    #Set locations
    material_output.location = (844.2685546875, 277.9710693359375)
    principled_bsdf.location = (-45.90791320800781, 50.614837646484375)
    shader_to_rgb.location = (290.79669189453125, 97.51869201660156)
    color_ramp.location = (-67.09164428710938, 55.0496826171875)
    node_1.location = (568.9841918945312, 199.96200561523438)
    
    #Set dimensions
    material_output.width, material_output.height = 140.0, 100.0
    principled_bsdf.width, principled_bsdf.height = 240.0, 100.0
    shader_to_rgb.width, shader_to_rgb.height = 140.0, 100.0
    color_ramp.width, color_ramp.height = 240.0, 100.0
    node_1.width, node_1.height = 300.3999938964844, 266.20001220703125
    
    #initialize toon_shader links
    #shader_to_rgb.Color -> color_ramp.Fac
    toon_shader.links.new(shader_to_rgb.outputs[0], color_ramp.inputs[0])
    #principled_bsdf.BSDF -> shader_to_rgb.Shader
    toon_shader.links.new(principled_bsdf.outputs[0], shader_to_rgb.inputs[0])
    #color_ramp.Color -> material_output.Surface
    toon_shader.links.new(color_ramp.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
    return toon_shader



   
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class (SimpleShaderEditor)
    bpy.utils.register_class (Remove_Shader)
    bpy.utils.register_class (toon_shader)
        
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class (SimpleShaderEditor)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class (Remove_Shader)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class (toon_shader)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


The blender addon works in the text editor but does not work when I save the .py file and try to import it using the edit import file in the addons menu. I removed any from import as statements and replaced them with just normal imports I tried to add a sleep right before any of the classes get called to hopefully make sure blender could initialize any imports before I Tried to call them. I do not know what is wrong because it works totally fine in the blender text editor Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

I'm not gonna rewrite your whole addon, I'll leave that to you. But your problems stems from the way you're organizing your addon and the relevant data it accesses. Creating a global mat variable in the declaration of your class is a bad idea, one because it's generally not advised to use global variables for a handful of reasons I won't get into, But also because this code has to be run at startup before bpy.data even exists in memory. Operators are meant to be like a tool you pull out, do what you need with it and then put everything back where it came from once finished. What you're doing is like trying to put the nails into the boards you want to build a house with before they've been pulled off the truck, hoping they'll still be in place when you're on the ladder with your hammer in hand.
There are a number of ways to go about organizing your operators; a lot of people put everything including new methods/functions, and hidden properties directly into the operator class declaration. This is harder to test/debug and can lead to stale data issues so I personally like putting all the actual functionality of the operator into it's own class and then instantiating that on execution of the operator. Something approximately like this:
import bpy


# put all the stuff that doesn't pertain to properties
# and execution logic into a separate class for managing the 
# data for your operation. If it's not gonna be visible to the 
# user in a slider or checkbox or w/e then it should prolly be in
# a separate class. This makes sense from a higher-level programming
# pov, but also prevents alot of issues with stale or restricted
# data access that can happen with custom operators.

class ShaderManager:
    def __init__(self, shader_name):
        self.shader_name = shader_name 
        self.mat = self.get_or_create_material(self.shader_name)
        self.populate_shader_graph()

    # this `get_or_create_material` method
    # replaces this part of your code in your toon_shader class:
    # ->     global mat
    # ->     mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Toon Shader")
    # ->     mat.use_nodes = True
    
    def get_or_create_material(self, shader_name):
        try:
            mat = bpy.data.materials[shader_name]
        except KeyError:
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=shader_name)
        mat.use_nodes = True
        return mat
    
    # this replaces your function for Toon_Shader_ini()
    def populate_shader_graph(self):
        # here instead of using a global variable you just reference
        # the ShaderManager object's mat attribute
        
        toon_shader = self.mat.node_tree
        #start with a clean node tree
        for node in toon_shader.nodes:
            toon_shader.nodes.remove(node)
        
        # ... etc
        # ... etc

    
# follow naming conventions, not only for broad Python conventions
# e.g class declarations should use CapCase
# but also Blender specific conventions 
# e.g. operator classes should follow the {CATEGORY}_{OT}_{op_name_in_snake_case}
# menus class are the same except MT instead of OT etc

class SIMPLESHADER_OT_create_toon_shader(bpy.types.Operator):

    """Adds a Toon Shader to the selected object"""
    bl_idname = "sse_object.toon_shader"
    bl_label = "Adds a Toon Shader to the selected object"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll (cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.object
        ShaderMgr = ShaderManager("Toon Shader")
        toon_material = ShaderMgr.mat
        if obj.data.materials:
            # If the object already has materials, replace the first one with the Toon Shader
            obj.data.materials[0] = toon_material
        else:
            # If the object has no materials, append the Toon Shader
            obj.data.materials.append(toon_material)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Shader Added!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

